# Adding a regex condition to a listcomp in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everyone or anyone,

The aim: The aim is to divide text by 50 characters, BUT if there is a `.` in the sentence, Break and make start from the point after the `.`

I have this code

```
txt = "Greatly cottage thought fortune no mention he. Of mr certainty arranging am smallness by conveying. Him plate you allow built grave. Sigh sang nay sex high yet door game. She dissimilar was favourable unreserved nay expression contrasted saw. Past her find she like bore pain open. Shy lose need eyes son not shot. Jennings removing are his eat dashwood. Middleton as pretended listening he smallness perceived. Now his but two green spoil drift."

n = 50
some_text = [txt[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(txt), n)]
```

This code divides the text into a list of strings made of 50 chars, perfect, but I also
need to add the condition of the `.`. If a `.` occurs, it must break and create string,
and continue from that point.

What it looks like:

```
print(some_text)

['Greatly cottage thought fortune no mention he. Of ', 'mr certainty arranging am smallness by conveying. ', 'Him plate you allow built grave. Sigh sang nay sex', ' high yet door game. She dissimilar was favourable', ' unreserved nay expression contrasted saw. Past he', 'r find she like bore pain open. Shy lose need eyes', ' son not shot. Jennings removing are his eat dashw', 'ood. Middleton as pretended listening he smallness', ' perceived. Now his but two green spoil drift.']
```

What I want it to look like:

```
['Greatly cottage thought fortune no mention he.', 'Of mr certainty arranging am smallness by'

'conveying.' 'Him plate you allow built grave.'
```

and so on...

Comment: So you want to first split the text at `'.'` and then you want to split each resulting part into 50-character chunks?

Comment: I want to split into 50 char chunks but if a '.' occurs, split at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `txt.split('.')` with `textwrap.wrap`?

```
from textwrap import wrap

txt = "Greatly cottage thought fortune no mention he. Of mr certainty arranging am smallness by conveying. Him plate you allow built grave. Sigh sang nay sex high yet door game. She dissimilar was favourable unreserved nay expression contrasted saw. Past her find she like bore pain open. Shy lose need eyes son not shot. Jennings removing are his eat dashwood. Middleton as pretended listening he smallness perceived. Now his but two green spoil drift."

lines = []
for sentence in txt.split('.'):
    if not sentence.strip():
        continue
    for line in wrap(sentence+'.', 50):
        lines.append(line.strip())

# print lines:
print(*lines, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
Greatly cottage thought fortune no mention he.
Of mr certainty arranging am smallness by
conveying.
Him plate you allow built grave.
Sigh sang nay sex high yet door game.
She dissimilar was favourable unreserved nay
expression contrasted saw.
Past her find she like bore pain open.
Shy lose need eyes son not shot.
Jennings removing are his eat dashwood.
Middleton as pretended listening he smallness
perceived.
Now his but two green spoil drift.
```